# Does anyone know how to remove this weird shaddow?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Image demonstrating it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAYLn.png)

On android this is happening, but not on iOS and absolutely don't know why. Does anyone know why this happens?
I don't know if it is the fact that I don't have an `AppBar()` in any of the screens or anything else.

**My main.dart file with theme data**

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: "Desafios UNO",
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  
  theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: const Color(0xFFFF5F00),
    
      snackBarTheme: const SnackBarThemeData(
        backgroundColor:  Color(0xFF121212),
      ),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          systemOverlayStyle:
              SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Color(0xFF121212)),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
              letterSpacing: 1.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 16,
              color: Color(0xFF121212)),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFF121212)))),
  builder: (_, child) => Unfocus(child: child!),
  home: const HomeScreen(),
);
```

Comment: You set your `appbar` color to transparent you should have a designated `appBar`backGroundColor that would match the one in your design.
Using transparent is bad practice when trying to use colors.

Comment: I think the extendBodyBehindScaffold property in the Scaffold class is what you're looking for, you should set it to true. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBodyBehindAppBar.html

Comment: Unfortunately, none of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Aftermath**

After a lot of research I was able to fix it by adding this:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemNavigationBarColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 246, 247, 246), //specific color because of the color scheme of my app, you can put whatever you want 
  systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark ,// navigation bar color
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, 
  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark// status bar color
));
```

If you happen to find this thread and be on the same boat as I was, just add this lines of code before the `return` on your `Widget Build` method.

Also, make sure to import the ***services.dart*** file

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

I hope you found this helpfull.

Thanks to everyone that responded!